# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory when pasting a file into watched folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an build an app with node.js that watches an folder.

the basic implementation is:

```
fs.watch("./folder", async (eventType, filename) => { ... })
```

Now i have a test script that generates an file and place it into this `./folder` to see if my app works correct. my problem i face is that i get this error

> [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\PontonXP-Messenger-4.0.1-Windows\data\hotfolder-1\inbox\DATEN_CRMSG.xml']
> {   errno: -4058,   code: 'ENOENT',   syscall: 'open',   path:
> 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\PontonXP-Messenger-4.0.1-Windows\data\hotfolder-1\inbox\DATEN_CRMSG.xml'
> }

This happens when i try to write an file with `fs.writeFile`

```
export const writeFile = (path: string, file: string) => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    fs.writeFile(path, file, (err) => {
      if (err) return rej(err);
      res("Done");
    });
  });
};
```

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: try this `fs.watch("folder", async (eventType, filename) => { ... })`

Comment: Well the error message is pretty clear: you're trying to do something that involves a file that does not exist. Make sure the path you're trying to create involves folders that all exist.

Comment: @Anilkumar why would that make any difference?